# How to normalize/standardize time-inputs for a neuronal network?

Tags: input, neural-network, aforge

Im using AForge to build a Neuronal network.

But I have a hard time to define my input parameters. In my training Data, one input value is the time of an event.

As far as I know the input values should be between -1 and +1?

I cant figure out what the best way is to normalize/standardize the time-value.

One way would be to choose a min- and a max-value. The min value would be -1 and the max-value is 1. But then the network would stop working for values outside this timeframe or when the timeframe is to big, the difference between the inputs will be very small.

I thought of splitting the time value into several input values (like minute, hour, day, month, year) and use this as a several inputs but this moves the problem just to the "year"-input.

Another way is to use a logarithmic scale.

Are there any best practices for this or a good possibility I just did not think of?

**Update:**

The input consists of:

- A module number
- the time it was opened
- the user who opened it
- ...

Output:

- the module number of the module which will likley opened next

Answer (score 0):

You can just use timesteps.
You probably have dataset something like that:

```
12/13/2012 01:00,23,345,235,235,644,757,
12/13/2012 01:02,455,325,235578,23524,6413,757567,
12/13/2012 01:08,123,125,2375,23554,64123,75778,
...,
12/13/2019 07:33,244,245,231235,2158935,6567944,7567557
```

You can drop your first column:

```
23,345,235,235,644,757,
455,325,235578,23524,6413,757567,
123,125,2375,23554,64123,75778,
...,
244,245,231235,2158935,6567944,7567557
```

and work with your data directly.
Check this article https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-supervised-learning/. Hope it helps.

Comment: You want me to just dont use a time-value as an input for a Neuronal network?

Comment: If you could provide an example of your dataset it would be easier to advise. Well... I had experience working with stock market. Most common way to define time value as input value is to group up data in time frames(weekly,hourly,etc).

Comment: I added the dataset to the question.